# Simulate 3D space in 2D

Tags: graphics, game-physics

I'm starting to code my first game and I want to make simple 2D sprite game. However I want to simulate 3D space & physics and am searching for some tutorial/guide/algorithms that would teach me the basics... but so far without luck.

Do you have any recommendations? Books? I don't care about programming language, any language will do as I can read algorithms in most languages and for start I just want to understand exiting solutions for 3D -> 2D problem.

Thanks!

Edit: I am not so much looking into physics for now as for projecting 3D space onto 2D

This is the best article I've found on subject: http://www.create-games.com/article.asp?id=2138

Another great article: http://pixwiki.bafsoft.com/mags/5/articles/circle/sincos.htm

Comment: Hi. So your game will actually be 3D, but the user can only walk in 2-Dimensions? If so, any 3D physics book will do as the physics will be working in 3D space. Your world would be 3D, but the camera will be flat on (with a slight tilt) to give a 3D view. (This isn't an answer, as I just wanted to clarify what you wanted)

Comment: Well, you are right. I guess I am looking for a way to project a 3D world on 2D, than take users input from that 2D and calculate how that affects my 3D world... and show it of course...

Comment: lol on 1D :)  [adding 15 characters]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1980's games systems used [parallax techniques](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallax_scrolling) to give a feeling of depth with 2D implementations.

Comment: Yeah... these are the things I'm looking for... that page you gave me led me to more nice pages:

http://www.gorenfeld.net/lou/pseudo/
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pole_Position_%28video_game%29

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about the process of rendering a 3D scene as a 2D image (i.e. on a screen), then you'll want to look at [perspective projections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection). It's quite heavy on maths, though, and involves a lot of work with transformation matrices and linear algebra.

You should make sure you're up to scratch on both linear algebra and calculus if you're planning on creating a 3D physics-based game.

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing 2D, you might like to start with simple 2D physics. I'd especially recommend [Box2D](http://www.box2d.org/) for that purpose! It's easy to learn and integrate, and it's tutorials will let you on the basics of physics in games.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what language you're using, but OpenGL and variants of it exist, I believe from internet search, for several common programming environments.

It provides some very powerful tools for creating 3D objects, setting viewports into the virtual 3D space, placing lights, defining textures.  It might take a couple weeks of spare time to master, but it certainly spares you doing much of the perspective math you would need to roll your own 3D tools.  There are good tutorials on the intenet.

Good luck